# Disabling asp validation controls in a hidden Panel

Tags: javascript

In my asp page I used 2 asp panel controls.The second panel was **not visible** as the style property of it was set to hidden.Panel 2 is displayed through javascript code which change the style property to **visible** according to the value of a **checkbox** in panel 1.
On postback although the **panel 2** is hidden its asp validations are pop up and the postback is not happening.I tried to disable the server **controls** via javascript,but its not working.

Can someone help me in this?

```
function DisablePanel() {
var div_to_disable =document.getElementById('<%=Panel1.ClientID%>').getElementsByTagName("input");
var children = div_to_disable;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
children[i].disabled = true;
    };
}
function EnablePanel() {
var div_to_disable = document.getElementById('<%=Panel1.ClientID     %>').getElementsByTagName("input");
    var children = div_to_disable; //.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        children[i].disabled = false;
    };
}
   function ShowPanel2() {
   var panel = document.getElementById('<%=Panel2.ClientID %>');
   if (panel.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
       EnablePanel();
       panel.style.visibility = 'visible';
   }
   else { DisablePanel();
       panel.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These posts might help you; Basically you have to just call ASP.NET inbuilt JS function " ValidatorEnable" after the disable method call

[Enable/disable asp.net validator controls within a specific "ValidationGroup" with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158052/enable-disable-asp-net-validator-controls-within-a-specific-validationgroup-wi)

http://geekswithblogs.net/jonasb/archive/2006/08/11/87708.aspx

Comment: Will it mean that disabling all controls in panel will not disable asp validation controls in the same panel and we have to explicitily disable it?