# How to enable and disable Required Validation group for fields and Expressions fields when a div is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a credit card transaction area in my form that I hide and show based on user's selection in an radio button group. With my credit card piece are required validations and required expressions that is in a validation group. I was wondering if I could get some help with enabling and disabling this validation group in J Query. Thanks in advance for your guys' help!

Comment: @Win what are your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a class that indicates whether a field should be validated or not, so when a field that should be validated is hidden, just remove the class. Add it again when it is displayed.

A more elegant solution is to disable validation of hidden fields:

```
$('myform').submit(function() {
    $('myform').find('validate:visible').forEach( ... );
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah I do have a validation group on them

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.NET built-in JavaScript function to enable and disable validators

```
var validtorObject = document.getElementById('validtorObjectID');    
ValidatorEnable(validtorObject, false);
```

And this SO answer gives you easy way to disable all controls inside a validation group using JQuery

[Enable/disable asp.net validator controls within a specific "ValidationGroup" with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158052/enable-disable-asp-net-validator-controls-within-a-specific-validationgroup-wi)

Comment: Would this work the same as using the validation group name for the validation Id?

Comment: Validation groups are different, this is just to disable individual validators.

Comment: Check out the edit on how to disable whole ValidationGroup as well.

Answer (score 0):

to disable required validator you can try

```
 ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("<%=RequiredFieldValidatorID %>"), false);
```

Comment: Would this work the same as using the validation group name for the validation Id?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `CausesValidation="False"`

CausesValidation property determines whether validation must be performed on button click or not, if asp.net validation control are used. It can be either true or false. By default it is true.

It is mostly used for Cancel/Reset button, where we don't want to perform any kind of validations.

```
protected void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   creditCardTextbox.Attributes.Add("CausesValidation", "False");
}
```